# Laravel : Data not inserted on the table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Facing a problem on submit form data.

When I fill up all form data then it is inserted into the database. But when I fill only mandatory field data and leave other data as blank it is not working and it redirect to the same form.

On removing validation also not working.

My controller function code:

```
public function save(Request $request) {
    try {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Activity::rules());
        $activity = Activity::saveOrUpdate($request);
        if($activity !== false) {
            return redirect()->route('lists-activity')->with('success', trans('activity data added successfully.!!'));
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', "Unable to save activity data.!!")->withInput();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
       return back()->with('error', "Unable to save activity data.!!")->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

My model code :

```
  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

 class Activity extends Model
 {
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'category_id',
    'title',
    'description',
    'country_id',
    'city_id',
    'latitude',
    'longitude',
    'addressOne',
    'addressTwo',
    'hours_recomended',
    'hours_fixed',
    'time_fixed',
    'start_time',
    'end_time',
    'file_type',
    'flag_image'
];


/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $timestamps = false;

public static function rules() {
    return [
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'country_id' => 'required',
        'city_id' => 'required',
        'hours_fixed' => 'required',
        'start_time' => 'required',
        'end_time' => 'required'
    ];
}
  public static function saveOrUpdate(Request $request) {
    try {
        $id = $request->get('id', false);
        $activity = false;
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, &$activity, $id) {

            $activity = $id ? Activity::findOrFail($id) : new Activity();
            $activity->fill($request->all());
            try {

                $activity->save();
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                throw $ex;
            }
        });
        return $activity;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }

} }
```

Form view :
[image]
Don't know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error message you are getting when redirecting back??

Comment: dd($request->all()) ;

Comment: when i chech getQueryLog() it return blank.

Comment: `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Activity::rules());`

Comment: @Sohel0415 try both way..edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like validation works and redirects back as it supposes to do.

Put `{{ dump($errors->all()) }}` to the view and you'll see errors in the form after submitting the form.

Also, use the `updateOrCreate()` which does exactly what you're trying to do and will help you to avoid errors:

```
public static function saveOrUpdate(Request $request) {
    return $this->updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->id], $request->all());
}
```

Comment: Not working..can you please modify my saveOrUpdate function.?

Comment: @Javed I've updated the answer. Looks like validation works and redirects you back with errors in the error bag, but you don't read these errors.

Comment: added form image ..check. only show error message which validation define.

Comment: @Javed the image shows that you're not filling required fields.

Comment: I just want to show you that the error bag define all messages which i print on form.when i fill up required fields it is not working and when i fill up all the form fields it is working.

Comment: @Javed as I said, it looks like one of the validation rules gives you an error and you just don't display it. Have you tried to fill required fields and `dump($errors->all())`?

Comment: yes i did..it returns only same validation which i applied.`array:6 [▼
  0 => "The category id field is required."
  1 => "The title field is required."
  2 => "The country id field is required."
  3 => "The city id field is required."
  4 => "The start time field is required."
  5 => "The end time field is required."
]`

Comment: may be you can share your blade file with us

Comment: @Javed this happens when you fill all these 6 fields? I'm sorry, I just don't get what the problem is.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin no. submit form without filling any fields return this only 6 validation.when i check error bag.

Comment: @Javed but this is normal. Fill these fields.